# value not getting updated in the controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using a form control which has set of input boxes.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">    
  <input ng-model="editPagename" class="form-control" required/>
  <input ng-model="editUrl" class="form-control" required/>
</form>
```

The value of `editPagename` is not getting updated in the scope and it's not even entering in the function.

```
$scope.$watch('editPagename', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  console.log(newVal);
});
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: check your console,Is it giving any error ? Your posted code looks ok. Post your controller.

Comment: Please share the controller and how do you handled it?

Comment: I have updated answer.Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$scope.$watch( function() {
 return $scope.editPagename;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me.Here what I have tried.

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">    
    <input ng-model ="editPagename" class="form-control" required/>
    <input ng-model="editUrl" class="form-control" required/>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS :

```
app.controller("testCtrl",function($scope){ 

 $scope.$watch( 'editPagename', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
   }); 
})
```

Its logging in the console.

EDIT CODE :

Its better to use Objec model rather than primitive datatype.

Here is the code snippet.

HTMl

```
<div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">    
    <input ng-model ="objEdit.editPagename" class="form-control" required/>
    <input ng-model="objEdit.editUrl" class="form-control" required/>
    </form>
    {{objEdit}}
</div>
```

JS :

```
app.controller("testCtrl",function($scope){ 

  $scope.objEdit = {};
```

})

Comment: Not an answer, You should have commented only.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been indicated that $scope will go bye bye in the future (you can have a read [at this "preparing for the future of angularjs" on airpair](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/preparing-for-the-future-of-angularjs), [also a link the the youtube video of the ng-europe talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNmWybAyBHI)), and you might want to write your code for easy upgrading to 2.x

So, unless you absolutely need $scope for something, try this:

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
    <p>Hello {{vm.name}}!</p>
    <div>
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">    
        <input data-ng-model ="vm.name" data-ng-change="vm.checkValue(vm.name)" class="form-control" required/>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
```

app.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  vm = this;
  vm.name = "world";
  vm.checkValue = checkValue;

  function checkValue(value){
    console.log(value);
  }
});
```

[And a plunker link with the example.](http://plnkr.co/edit/wgDZSKc2LVyuMN59my2C?p=preview)
No $scope needed. And of what I can tell, does what you are asking.